# Brownian motion transition density question

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-analysis

Let $Y_t = M_t - W_t$ where $M_t$ is the running maximum of brownian motion and $W_t$ is brownian motion. I want to  show that $P^0[Y_{t+s} \in dy| Y_t = x] = p(s,x,y)+p(s,x,-y)$ where $p$ is the transition density of brownian motion.

This problem is in Karatzas and Shreve (pg 124) and actually the solution is there as well. However, the solution is not easy to understand. One part of the solution reads as follows:

For $b>m \geq w$,$b \geq a$, $m \geq 0$

$P^0[W_{t+s}\in da,M_{t+s}\in db|W_t=w,M_t=m]$

$=P^0[W_{t+s} \in da, max_{0 \leq u \leq s} W_{t+u} \in db | W_t = w, M_t = m]$

$= P^w[W_s \in da, M_s \in db]$

How is this step justified? Don't we need $(W,M)$ to be a Markov family for this? How can we show that this is a Markov family?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to prove that $(W,M)$ is a Markov process is to note that, for every $t\geqslant0$ and $s\geqslant0$, $$W_{t+s}=W_t+\bar W_s,$$ where $\bar W=(\bar W_s)_{s\geqslant0}$ is a Brownian motion starting from $0$ and independent of the sigma-algebra $\mathcal W_t=\sigma(W_u\,;\,0\leqslant u\leqslant t)$. Furthermore, considering $\bar M$ the maximum process of $\bar W$, one has
$$
M_{t+s}=\max\{M_t,W_t+\bar M_s\},
$$
for every $s\geqslant0$, hence the distribution of $(W_{t+s},M_{t+s})_{s\geqslant0}$ conditionally on  $\mathcal W_t$ depends on $(W_t,M_t)$ only, as desired.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Do you happen to know why the above equalities are justified? I just edited out a typo that might have made them seem like nonsense to you earlier. I have no idea how to handle the extra dependence on $M_t = m$. I originally thought that maybe we needed the pair $(W,M)$ to be a markov family but now I am not sure. Your input on this would be extremely helpful. Thanks.

Comment: The step in your post you are referring to is odd since it makes no difference between the cases $b=m$ and $b\gt m$, and it seems to ignore that the case $b\lt m$ is impossible.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Let us assume that we have b>m here. Even with this, I still do not know how to handle the extra dependence on $M_t = m$ and to justify the steps.

Comment: As I said, there is a problem with your steps since, conditionally on $M_t=m$, the event $[M_{t+s}=m]$ has positive probability.

Comment: But $b>m$ now so aren't we no longer looking at that event?